# Combining cat with knife ssh crashes bash

Tags: ssh, chef, knife

I'm trying to transfer a ssh key from one node to other using chef's knife ssh combined with the cat command on the key

`cat ~/.ssh/001.rsa | knife ssh -i ~/.ssh/authkey.rsa 'name:myserver' 'mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/id_rsa' -a cloud.local_ipv4`

But as soon as I ran this, the bash behaves like its processing something, but it gets stuck...